# SQL Sever 2008 - How to combine rows with related data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to combine rows with related data, following example will make it clear. I'm using this script:

```
SELECT AlertName, COUNT(AlertName) as NumAlerts
FROM Alerts
GROUP BY AlertName
ORDER BY AlertName
```

And results is:

```
AlertName                NumAlets
------------------------|---------------
...
Windows Services SQL     9
...
Windows Services - Core  7
Windows Services Core    271
Windows Services: Core   90
...
```

But I would like to combine (group) these rows and summarize NumAlets to get this result:

```
AlertName                NumAlets
------------------------|---------------
...
Windows Services SQL     9
Windows Services (Core)  368  
...
```

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT rs.AlertName, COUNT(1) Totals
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN AlertName LIKE 'Windows Services%Core' 
            THEN 'Windows Services (Core)'
        WHEN AlertName LIKE 'Windows Services%SQL' 
            THEN 'Windows Services (SQL)'
       ELSE AlertName END AlertName
    from ALERTS) RS
Group By rs.AlertName
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a table to translate the various spellings into one:

```
DECLARE @Translation TABLE (
    AlertName varchar(100),
    CommonAlertName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Translation (AlertName, CommonAlertName)
    VALUES ('Windows Services SQL', 'Windows Services SQL'),
           ('Windows Services - Core', 'Windows Services (Core)'),
           ('Windows Services Core', 'Windows Services (Core)'),
           ('Windows Services: Core', 'Windows Services (Core)')

SELECT T.CommonAlertName, SUM(A.NumAlerts) AS NumAlerts
FROM Alerts A
INNER JOIN @Translation T ON A.AlertName = T.AlertName
GROUP BY T.CommonAlertName
```

Comment: it only displays grouped rows ans skips all the rest :( But if you use `LEFT JOIN` instead it displays grouped ones and `NULL` for all the rest! How to make it display grouped rows with all the rest rows?

Comment: It's a pointer. The rest is up to you to adapt to fit with your requirement. SO isn't a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Zoff' answer is reasonable, but the logic should be `left join` so a translation does not have to exist in the translation table:

```
with translation as (
      select 'Windows Services SQL' as AlertName, 'Windows Services SQL' as CommonAlertName union ll
      select 'Windows Services - Core', 'Windows Services (Core)' union all
      select 'Windows Services Core', 'Windows Services (Core)' union all
      select 'Windows Services: Core', 'Windows Services (Core)'
     )
SELECT COALESCE(T.CommonAlertName, A.AlertName), SUM(A.NumAlerts) AS NumAlerts
FROM Alerts A LEFT JOIN 
     Translation T
     ON A.AlertName = T.AlertName
GROUP BY COALESCE(T.CommonAlertName, A.AlertName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also accomplish this with a function that filters out all non-alphanumeric characters so that strings like "Windows Services - Core" and "Windows Services (Core)" both become "WindowsServicesCore" and match each other.

The following function comes from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-udf-function-to-parse-alphanumeric-characters-from-string/

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_ParseAlphaChars
(
@string VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT
    SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z]%', @string)

    WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @string = STUFF(@string, @IncorrectCharLoc, 1, '')
        SET @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Za-z]%', @string)
    END

    SET @string = @string
    RETURN @string
END
```

and the query looks like the one below.

```
select min(AlertName) as AlertName, COUNT(*) as NumAlerts
from Alerts
group by dbo.UDF_ParseAlphaChars( AlertName)
```